# Review queue oddness

Tags: support, vote-to-close

There are currently 55 questions in the close queue on DBA.se - Many are old, and it all seems a bit weird that old questions now have 4 out of 5 close votes. https://dba.stackexchange.com/review

Has a user been deleted, thus causing the number of close votes to revert back to 4 from 5 for these 55 questions?

I'll add that I've never seen more than a couple of things waiting in the review queue, as the regulars on DBA.se are pretty good at keeping on top of things.

EDIT: it's 30 days since I changed my display name. Is there a badly-written batch job that may have removed my previous close votes? Another user reports seeing the same number of votes, but nothing to actually review.

[image: What I see now]

Comment: FWIW: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:c00t0-Sg_w8J:dba.stackexchange.com/review

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, [it's a new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/193939).

I think OCD may generate a user script for my browser :) Don't like numbers making me stare when I have no control over them!

Comment: I'll clear it out for you if it's bugging you that much... Don't know that you necessarily want me to do that though. Might want to ask your mods to do it.

Comment: It's fine - I guess it'll settle once others have contributed. Thanks anyway

Comment: @shog9 I just assumed it was a bug as we were all seeing different things. Maybe this shows there should have been some kind of notification (a single viewe closable drop down maybe?) to highlight such a significant change going live?

Comment: I think we should put the build number in the top bar, circled in orange, with a link to MSE.

Comment: Haha. Just for my user? :)

Comment: Tell you what, just enable the toolbar for chat.se and I'll be happy...

Comment: It is. Just not in any chat rooms.

Comment: The Heap beta test time!